# Puzzled error... an identifier is already declared in DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, decorator

I am using an example to learn decorator in JS.  When I run the the example code below as a snippet in Chrome DevTools, I got an error msg:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'wrapped' has already been declared
>       at :1:1

However, when I use Node.js to run the same code in terminal, everything is fine.  Changing the variable name from `const wrapped = loggingDecorator(doSomething);` to `const hello = loggingDecorator(doSomething);` told me it's not the problem b/c the error simply became:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'hello' has already been declared
>       at :1:1

Anyone has an idea what's going on?

```
function doSomething(name) {
  console.log('Hello, ' + name);
}

function loggingDecorator(wrapped_func) {
  return function() {
    console.log('Starting');
    const result = wrapped_func.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log('Finished');
    return result;
  }
}

const wrapped = loggingDecorator(doSomething);
```

Comment: What version of Chrome? I don't see that error, unless I run the snippet twice (and that's fine: running `const wrapped` twice *should* produce an error).

Comment: @apsillers , my version is Version 64.0.3282.167.  I just created another snippet, and got  the same error the first time I ran it.

Comment: Hm, that's very close to mine (mine ends with `.186`). Are you running any extensions (listed in `chrome://extensions`) that could be interfering? That's my only guess and it's not a great one -- I don't see how an extension would cause that behavior, but it's the only substantial difference I can think of. Also, I'm on Windows 10, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as mentioned in the comments `wrapped` might be already declared either in the page you are inspecting or by any extension. I would suggest you use one of following ways.

```
{
    function doSomething(name) {


    console.log('Hello, ' + name);
    }

    function loggingDecorator(wrapped_func) {
      return function() {
        console.log('Starting');
        const result = wrapped_func.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log('Finished');
        return result;
      }
    }

    const wrapped = loggingDecorator(doSomething);
}
```

or

place your code inside an iife

```
(function(){
function doSomething(name) {
  console.log('Hello, ' + name);
}

function loggingDecorator(wrapped_func) {
  return function() {
    console.log('Starting');
    const result = wrapped_func.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log('Finished');
    return result;
  }
}

const wrapped = loggingDecorator(doSomething);
})();
```